# How to get missing dates in column of table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a table with following records

```
DateIn      TimeIn
----------------------------
2019-02-01  09:31:00.0000000
2019-02-02  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-04  09:27:00.0000000
2019-02-05  09:34:00.0000000
2019-02-06  09:32:00.0000000
2019-02-09  09:38:00.0000000
2019-02-11  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-12  15:09:00.0000000
2019-02-13  09:31:00.0000000
2019-02-14  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-15  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-16  09:37:00.0000000
2019-02-18  09:33:00.0000000
2019-02-19  09:31:00.0000000
```

So 2019-02-03,2019-02-07,2019-02-08,2019-02-10,2019-02-17 are missing dates

so I want result in following format

```
DateIn      TimeIn
----------------------------
2019-02-01  09:31:00.0000000
2019-02-02  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-03  null
2019-02-04  09:27:00.0000000
2019-02-05  09:34:00.0000000
2019-02-06  09:32:00.0000000
2019-02-07  null
2019-02-08  null
2019-02-09  09:38:00.0000000
2019-02-10  null
2019-02-11  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-12  15:09:00.0000000
2019-02-13  09:31:00.0000000
2019-02-14  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-15  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-16  09:37:00.0000000
2019-02-17  null
2019-02-18  09:33:00.0000000
2019-02-19  09:31:00.0000000
```

For that I created the function 'GetAllDates' which return all dates between given dates and I used this function in following manner

```
Select 
    TA.DateIn, TA.TimeIn
from  
    [ES].[getAllDates]('20190201','20190228') DD 
left outer join   
    [ES].[tblAttendance] TA on Cast(TA.DateIn as date) = cast(DD.date as date) 
where 
    TA.PersonId = 21
```

This query returns the following results:

```
DateIn      TimeIn
----------------------------
2019-02-01  09:31:00.0000000
2019-02-02  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-04  09:27:00.0000000
2019-02-05  09:34:00.0000000
2019-02-06  09:32:00.0000000
2019-02-09  09:38:00.0000000
2019-02-11  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-12  15:09:00.0000000
2019-02-13  09:31:00.0000000
2019-02-14  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-15  09:35:00.0000000
2019-02-16  09:37:00.0000000
2019-02-18  09:33:00.0000000
2019-02-19  09:31:00.0000000
```

It is not the correct result.. Please help me to find the solution

Comment: Please add result of your above query in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `WHERE` query with the `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get `NULL` records.

```
SELECT TA.datein, 
       TA.timein 
FROM   [ES].[Getalldates]('20190201', '20190228') DD 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [ES].[tblattendance] TA 
                    ON Cast(TA.datein AS DATE) = Cast(DD.date AS DATE) 
                       AND TA.personid = 21
```

Answer (score 2):

One easy approach here is to left join a calendar table to your current table on the date, something like this:

```
WITH dates AS (
    select date from [ES].getAllDates('20190201','20190228')
)

SELECT
    d.date,
    t.TimeIn
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN [ES].[tblAttendance] t
    ON d.date = t.DateIn and t.PersonId = 21
ORDER BY
    d.date;
```

The answer by @PSK *might* work, assuming that your `tblAttendance` table actually already has data for every date present.  If it doesn't, then just moving the `WHERE` restriction to the `ON` clause might still leave some holes in the dates present.

Comment: I tried this and it works perfectly but I used my function in 'dates' and moved the where condition to the On clause...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create your date records, then make left join with your current record.

```
    GO

        DECLARE  @arrival_date date = '2019-01-01',
             @leaving_date date = '2019-02-01'

    ;WITH DD AS (
    SELECT @arrival_date as date_
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day,1,date_) as date)
    FROM DD
    WHERE date_ < @leaving_date
    )
    select DD.date_ as DateIn,  TA.TimeIn as TimeIn from DD LEFT OUTER JOIN [ES].[tblattendance] TA 
                ON Cast(TA.datein AS DATE) = Cast(DD.date_ AS DATE) 
                   AND TA.personid = 21 

    GO
```